# jQuery accessing elements using variables

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/script1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>

</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

Script which works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('li:nth-child(2)').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Now I just use a variable to do the same thing and it does not work anymore.

```
var $var = $('li:nth-child(2)');
$(document).ready(function () {
$var.fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Can anyone please tell me the correct syntax.
I have just started learning jQuery and know it is probably a simple mistake but I just cannot figure it out.
Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it into the `document ready function` when the `li` actually exists:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var $var = $('li:nth-child(2)');
   $var.fadeOut('fast')
});
```

Comment: thanks, it works now.
small doubt, when I declare it outside, doesn't it make it a global variable and hence accessible everywhere?

Comment: well, generally yes. But since you are selecting an element that doesn't exist at that time, your variable will always be and stay empty. But yes - you created a global variable :)

Answer (score 1):

The variable needs to be assigned inside the `$(document).ready(function() { }`